# Can i Configure ram size in browserstack Android devices?

Tags: automation

I want to configure the ram size of browser stack device is it possible to do ?.
I need to stick some particular device .

Comment: You should better contact BrowserStack about this if you didn't found any info in the Resources section.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I contacted Browser stack , It is not possible to  configure the Ram size and other configuration because all the devices which are in BrowserStack are Real not virtual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Browserstack or pCloudy platform we can not configure RAM size and all because they are not virtual devices. They are the Real devices and we will be accessing the images of those Real devices.